# Question on odd positive integers and Fermat factors

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modules

Let $n$ be an odd positive integer, Let $o=\operatorname{ord}_n 2$ be the order of 2 modulo $n$ and $m$ the period of $1/n, k$ is number of distinct odd residues contained in set $\{2^1,2^2,...,2^{n−1}\}$ modulo $n$.

If $o,m$ and $k$ in the set $\{2,4,8,...\}$ and $k$ divide $n-1$, then $n$ is item in the sequence $17, 257, 641, 65537, …$.

It seems all known items in the sequence are Fermat factors, How come?

P.S.:
$167772161$ also is item in the sequence, could someone have a full check between $65537$ and $167772161$?

Comment: also see: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343851/question-on-odd-positive-integers-and-fermat-factors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*this is a copy of my answer which I gave originally on math-overflow, where possibly your question shall be closed soon. There has also been an initial description of an iterative procedure to compute your set of numbers - I'm referring to that description here*

You  give a game of iteration on numbers, which I'd like to rewrite for some given positive odd number $z$ and an initial $a=1$ :
$$  b = {z+a\over 2^A } \tag 1
$$
where $A$ is taken such that $b$ is odd again.

You iterate that formula until this cycles:
$$  c = {z+b\over 2^B } \qquad d = {z+c\over 2^C } \qquad \cdots \qquad a = {z+h\over 2^H } \tag 2
$$
Let us denote the number of iterates with $N$ and the sum of exponents $S=A+B+C+\cdots+H$ .
You wonder now about the observation that some numbers $z$ satisfy multiple conditions: that $N$ is a power of $2$, that $S$ is a power of $2$, (and about the period in decimal expansion of $1/z$ but which I shall not discuss here).

---

Let us look at some simple to detect properties.

- **What numbers $z$ have a cycle of $N=1$ ?**
  this means $b=a$ and constructing a formula gives (here is $S=A$)
  $$\begin{array}{rll} a &= { z+a\over 2^S } \\
      a2^S &= z+a \\
      z &=a(2^S-1) 
    \end{array} \tag {3.1}
  $$ 
  $\qquad \qquad $ Assuming $ a=1 $ gives the set of solutions
  $$ \begin{array}{rll}
      z &\in \{1,3,7,15,\ldots\}   \\
      A=S &\in \{1,2,3,4,\ldots\}
   \end{array}  \tag {3.2} $$
- **What numbers $z$ have a cycle of $N=2$ ?**
  this means $c=a$ in definition (2) and a formula gives (here $S=A+B$)
  $$\begin{array}{rll} b &= { z+a\over 2^A } && a &= { z+b\over 2^B } \\
       a &= { z+{ z+a\over 2^A }\over 2^B } & 
      =  { z2^A+ z+a \over 2^{A+B} }  \\
      a2^S -a &=   z2^A+ z   \\
      z &= a{ 2^S-1 \over 2^A+1 } & \left(= a{ (2^S-1)(2^{A}-1) \over 2^{2A}-1 }\right)
    \end{array} \tag {4.1}
  $$ 
  $\qquad \qquad $ Assuming $ a=1 $ gives the set of solutions
  $$ \Tiny \begin{array}{rr|ll}
  z & S & A & B \\ \hline
  1 & 2 & 1 & 1  \\
  5 & 4 & 1 & 3  \\
  21 & 6 & 1 & 5  \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \hline
  3 & 4 & 2 & 2  \\
  51 & 8 & 2 & 6  \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \hline
  7 & 6 & 3 & 3  \\
  455 & 12 & 3 & 9  \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \hline
  15 & 8 & 4 & 4  \\
  3855 & 16 & 4 & 12  \\
  986895 & 24 & 4 & 20  \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \hline
  31 & 10 & 5 & 5  \\
  31775 & 20 & 5 & 15  \\
  32537631 & 30 & 5 & 25  \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \hline
  63 & 12 & 6 & 6  \\
  258111 & 24 & 6 & 18  \\
  1057222719 & 36 & 6 & 30  \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  \end{array}  \tag {4.2} $$
  This table displays easy to recognize patterns for setting up formulae for $z$ and $S,A,B$ for the $N=2$ case. One shot is surely
  $$ S=2A\cdot k \qquad \implies z={2^{2kA}-1\over2^A+1}=
  {(2^{2kA}-1)(2^{A}-1)\over 2^{2A}-1}$$
  and the left parenthese is always divisible by the denominator.
  For a better example: just to look at your question of $N=2^j$ && $ S=2^k$ for positive $j \le k$ we can extract cases for $j=1$, $N=2^j=2$ first
  $$ \Tiny \begin{array}{rr|ll}
  z & S & A & B \\ \hline
  1 & 2 & 1 & 1  \\
  5 & 4 & 1 & 3  \\
  3 & 4 & 2 & 2  \\
  85 & 8 & 1 & 7  \\
  51 & 8 & 2 & 6  \\
  15 & 8 & 4 & 4  \\
  21845 & 16 & 1 & 15  \\
  13107 & 16 & 2 & 14  \\
  3855 & 16 & 4 & 12  \\
  255 & 16 & 8 & 8  \\
  1431655765 & 32 & 1 & 31  \\
  858993459 & 32 & 2 & 30  \\
  252645135 & 32 & 4 & 28  \\
  16711935 & 32 & 8 & 24  \\
  65535 & 32 & 16 & 16  \\
  6148914691236517205 & 64 & 1 & 63  \\
  3689348814741910323 & 64 & 2 & 62  \\
  1085102592571150095 & 64 & 4 & 60  \\
  71777214294589695 & 64 & 8 & 56  \\
  281470681808895 & 64 & 16 & 48  \\
  4294967295 & 64 & 32 & 32  \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
  \end{array}  \tag {4.3} $$
  As by (4.1) with $a=1$ and $S=2^k$ we have analytically
  $$\begin{array}{rll} 
      z &= { 2^{2^k}-1 \over 2^A+1 } \\
        &= { (2^{2^{k-1}}+1)(2^{2^{k-2}}+1)...(2^1+1)(2^1-1)\over 2^{A}+1 }
        &= { 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 257 \cdot \ldots \cdot(2^{2^{k-1}}+1)\over 2^{A}+1 }
    \end{array} \tag {4.4}
  $$
  Because the parentheses in the numerator have no common factor, we can draw conclusions of possible $A$ in the denominator to make the fraction an integer value. <sub>(Empirically we can observe that all $A$ are perfect powers of $2$ and it is surely not difficult to prove this)</sub>

---

This can analoguously be extended to larger cycle-lengthes $N>2$ . It might furtherly be useful, to introduce a notation which combines the set of exponents $A,B,C,...$ with the resulting integer value $z$ in  a fully compacted form, say
$$ z = T(A_1,A_2,A_3,...,A_N) \tag 5$$
and look, for instance, at solutions $z$ for typical patterns of the exponents, like $z=T(1,1,1,...,1)$  or $z=T(1,1,...1,A_N)$ with $A_N\gt 1$ and $S=N-1+A$ to develop short formulae for the integer solutions.

I'm not going deeper into this nice game, but leave it to you as a suggestion how to approach analytical answers to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for your marvelous answer, and thank you for your contribution to this project. Your investment in time and energy was far beyond what I couldhave asked for.